# Primary Smtp Address valid format for New-Mailbox cmdlet

Tags: email, exchange, powershell, smtp, address

I am writing simple application that utilizes the **New-Mailbox** cmdlet. One of parameters that is set is **PrimarySmtpAddress**. Provided Smtp address must be valid, otherwise the call will fail.

I was trying to find some specification for valid smtp address, but wherever I look I see different rules.

Where can I find the specification of the valid Smtp address format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Standard for the Format of ARPA Internet Text Messages is located here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt . RFC822 is the number.

A snippet is quoted here: 
"Note:  For purposes of display, and when passing  such  structured information to other systems, such as mail protocol  services,  there  must  be  NO  linear-white-space between  words  that are separated by period (".") or at-sign ("@"). Section 6 is the address specification part that has the pieces you will need.

RFC 2821 is the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol standard (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). From section 2.3.10 and 4.5.3.1 are below.

2.3.10 Mailbox and Address

As used in this specification, an "address" is a character string
   that identifies a user to whom mail will be sent or a location into
   which mail will be deposited.  The term "mailbox" refers to that
   depository.  The two terms are typically used interchangeably unless
   the distinction between the location in which mail is placed (the
   mailbox) and a reference to it (the address) is important.  An
   address normally consists of user and domain specifications.  The
   standard mailbox naming convention is defined to be "local-
   part@domain": contemporary usage permits a much broader set of
   applications than simple "user names".  Consequently, and due to a
   long history of problems when intermediate hosts have attempted to
   optimize transport by modifying them, the local-part MUST be
   interpreted and assigned semantics only by the host specified in the
   domain part of the address.

4.5.3.1 Size limits and minimums

There are several objects that have required minimum/maximum sizes.
   Every implementation MUST be able to receive objects of at least
   these sizes.  Objects larger than these sizes SHOULD be avoided when
   possible.  However, some Internet mail constructs such as encoded
   X.400 addresses [16] will often require larger objects: clients MAY
   attempt to transmit these, but MUST be prepared for a server to
   reject them if they cannot be handled by it.  To the maximum extent
   possible, implementation techniques which impose no limits on the
   length of these objects should be used.

local-part
      The maximum total length of a user name or other local-part is 64
      characters.
   domain
      The maximum total length of a domain name or number is 255
      characters.

These documents are the specifications. They were published in 1982 and 2001 respectively.

Pretty much, you need a local-part@domain with no spaces. It can also contain the characters as specified in RFC822.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.